# ActionText image not stored in Azure (or any other service)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, actiontext

I have a Rails app with ActionText and ActiveStorage. So I have a ticket form with a description field, where ActionText is used. When I have the development environment configured to save the attachments to the local disk, everything works fine.

But when I configure it to use Azure storage, I see in the log that it seems to have uploaded (it returns an URL), but when I look in Azure, there is no stored image. This is the log:

```
Started POST "/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads" for ::1 at 2019-07-30 08:05:37 +0200
Processing by ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"blob"=>{"filename"=>"schaap.jpg", "content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "byte_size"=>56679, "checksum"=>"xNr4chw64aFTDzzvpmupBg=="}, "direct_upload"=>{"blob"=>{"filename"=>"schaap.jpg", "content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "byte_size"=>56679, "checksum"=>"xNr4chw64aFTDzzvpmupBg=="}}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "p83x87l66oibofrfmitfiqet120d"], ["filename", "schaap.jpg"], ["content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["byte_size", 56679], ["checksum", "xNr4chw64aFTDzzvpmupBg=="], ["created_at", "2019-07-30 06:05:38.851532"]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
  AzureStorage Storage (0.9ms) Generated URL for file at key: p83x87l66oibofrfmitfiqet120d (https://<blob name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/p83x87l66oibofrfmitfiqet120d?sp=rw&sv=2016-05-31&se=2019-07-30T06%3A10%3A38Z&sr=b&sig=%2BicDHTsLBXWCIr00m4cbmcg3U6il5LMfhVcKwTq8dns%3D)
Completed 200 OK in 867ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 5.7ms | Allocations: 70289)
```

This is in `config/development.rb`:

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

And this is in `storage.yml`:

```
local:
  service: AzureStorage
  storage_account_name: "<account-name>"
  storage_access_key: "<access-key>"
  container: "<container>"
```

And the proper gem is used:

```
gem 'azure-storage', require: false
```

So what is wrong? I tried the same with Digital Ocean spaces, but with the exact same result, so it is not Azure related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I've never used AzureStorage but I have used DigitalOcean Spaces. One thing you need to make sure you setup in order to enable direct uploads via ActiveStorage is CORS. I could be wrong but I think this may be the problem in your case.

I Googled "AzureStorage CORS" and found [MicroSoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services) on their CORS setup.

When using Digital Ocean, you'll want to use [their documentation to setup s3cmd](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/resources/s3cmd/) and use that to setup CORS for direct uploads.

After you set it up, you would create a CORS file (cors.xml) like so in your project:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://yourdomain.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Then, you would use the s3cmd tool to set it up with Digital Ocean, by running the following in your project directory:

```
s3cmd setcors cors.xml s3://yourbucketname
```

GoRails has a [great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=653&v=S-E2TNkXBV8) on how to do this.

Digital Ocean also has a [CORS user interface](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/how-to/cors/) but that doesn't normally do enough for my needs.

Comment: Aaaah CORS, completely forgot about that! Thanks, I will look into it.